# How to find first non-repetitive character from a string?

Tags: php, string

I've spent half day trying to figure out this and finally I got working solution.
However, I feel like this can be done in simpler way.
I think this code is not really readable.

Problem: Find first non-repetitive character from a string.

$string = "abbcabz"

In this case, the function should output "c".

The reason I use concatenation instead of `$input[index_to_remove] = ''`
in order to remove character from a given string
is because if I do that, it actually just leave empty cell so that my 
return value $input[0] does not not return the character I want to return.

For instance,

```
$str = "abc";
$str[0] = '';
echo $str;
```

This will output "bc"

But actually if I test,

```
var_dump($str);
```

it will give me:

```
string(3) "bc"
```

Here is my intention:

```
Given: input

while first char exists in substring of input {
  get index_to_remove
  input = chars left of index_to_remove . chars right of index_to_remove

  if dupe of first char is not found from substring
     remove first char from input 
}
return first char of input
```

Code:

```
function find_first_non_repetitive2($input) {

    while(strpos(substr($input, 1), $input[0]) !== false) {

        $index_to_remove = strpos(substr($input,1), $input[0]) + 1;
        $input = substr($input, 0, $index_to_remove) . substr($input, $index_to_remove + 1);

        if(strpos(substr($input, 1), $input[0]) == false) {
            $input = substr($input, 1);     
        }
    }
    return $input[0];
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<?php
    // In an array mapped character to frequency, 
    // find the first character with frequency 1.
    echo array_search(1, array_count_values(str_split('abbcabz')));
```

Answer (score 2):

Python:

```
def first_non_repeating(s):
 for i, c in enumerate(s):
  if s.find(c, i+1) < 0:
   return c
 return None
```

Same in PHP:

```
function find_first_non_repetitive($s)
{
 for($i = 0; i < strlen($s); $i++) {
  if (strpos($s, $s[i], $i+1) === FALSE)
   return $s[i];
 }
}
```

Comment: Actually this won't work for string such as "bbc".
<br />
It will return 2nd "b"
<br />
<$i = 0 > "bbc"
<br />
if strpos("bbc", "b", 0+1) is not false so skip the return.
<br />
<$i = 1> "bbc"
<br />
if strpos("bbc", "b", 1+1) is false thus returns $s[1] which is "b"
<br />
In this case we need to return "c" instead.
<br />

Comment: Ouch... This should be solved by adding array/set of seen characters and then it's the same as nik's solution below. Except he uses for-loop instead of strpos().

Comment: The PHP snippet complains of undeclared constant `i`.  If you know that your snippet is flawed, please either edit your advised script or delete the answer so that researchers don't waste their time reading an unusable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode:

```
Array N;

For each letter in string
  if letter not exists in array N
    Add letter to array and set its count to 1
  else
    go to its position in array and increment its count
End for

for each position in array N
  if value at potition == 1
    return the letter at position and exit for loop
  else
    //do nothing (for clarity)
end for
```

Basically, you find all distinct letters in the string, and for each letter, you associate it with a count of how many of that letter exist in the string.  then you return the first one that has a count of 1

The complexity of this method is O(n^2) in the worst case if using arrays.  You can use an associative array to increase it's performance.

Comment: Now that there answers which implement actual PHP code, this answer appears less helpful/value.  Please consider improving this answer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in much more readable code using some standard PHP functions:

```
// Count number of occurrences for every character
$counts = count_chars($string);

// Keep only unique ones (yes, we use this ugly pre-PHP-5.3 syntax here, but I can live with that)
$counts = array_filter($counts, create_function('$n', 'return $n == 1;'));

// Convert to a list, then to a string containing every unique character
$chars = array_map('chr', array_keys($counts));
$chars = implode($chars);

// Get a string starting from the any of the characters found
// This "strpbrk" is probably the most cryptic part of this code
$substring = strlen($chars) ? strpbrk($string, $chars) : '';

// Get the first character from the new string
$char = strlen($substring) ? $substring[0] : '';

// PROFIT!
echo $char;
```

Comment: This answer could use an update. `create_function` is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

1- use a sorting algotithm like mergesort (or quicksort has better performance with small inputs) 
2- then control repetetive characters

> - non repetetive characters will be single
> - repetetvives will fallow each other

Performance : sort + compare

Performance : O(n log n) + O(n) = O(n log n)

For example

```
    $string = "abbcabz"

    $string = mergesort ($string)
    // $string = "aabbbcz"
```

> Then take first char form string then compare with next one if match repetetive
>  
>   move to the next different character and compare
>  
>   first non-matching character is non-repetetive

Comment: First non-matching character in the sorted string ("aabbbcz") won't necessary will be the same as the first non-matching character in the original string ("abbzabc" for example).

Comment: This answer will be misleading to developers who do not know that `mergesort()` is not a native PHP function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function in Scala that would do it:

```
def firstUnique(chars:List[Char]):Option[Char] = chars match { 
  case Nil => None
  case head::tail => {
    val filtered = tail filter (_!=head)
    if (tail.length == filtered.length) Some(head) else firstUnique(filtered)
  }
}
```

scala> firstUnique("abbcabz".toList)
res5: Option[Char] = Some(c)

And here's the equivalent in Haskell:

```
firstUnique :: [Char] -> Maybe Char
firstUnique [] = Nothing
firstUnique (head:tail) = let filtered = (filter (/= head) tail) in
            if (tail == filtered) then (Just head) else (firstUnique filtered)
```

*Main> firstUnique "abbcabz"

Just 'c'

You can solve this more generally by abstracting over lists of things that can be compared for equality:

```
firstUnique :: Eq a => [a] -> Maybe a
```

Strings are just one such list.

Comment: This has always been a PHP question, but your implemention is only shown in non-PHP languages.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str="abbcade";
$checked= array(); // we will store all checked characters in this array, so we do not have to check them again

for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++)
{
    $c=0;
    if(in_array($str[$i],$checked)) continue;

    $checked[]=$str[$i];

    for($j=$i+1;$j<=strlen($str);$j++)
    {
        if($str[$i]==$str[$j]) 
        {
            $c=1;
            break;  
        }
    }
    if($c!=1) 
    {
        echo "First non repetive char is:".$str[$i]; 
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should replace your code...

```
$array = str_split($string);
$array = array_count_values($array);
$array = array_filter($array, create_function('$key,$val', 'return($val == 1);'));
$first_non_repeated_letter = key(array_shift($array));
```

Edit: spoke too soon.  Took out 'array_unique', thought it actually dropped duplicate values.  But character order *should* be preserved to be able to find the first character.

Comment: This answer calls `create_function()` which will cause a Fatal error. Even after that is fixed, this answer does not account for the possibility that a string may have no non-repeated characters. Proof: https://3v4l.org/aM73X

Answer (score 0):

Can be also done using `array_key_exists` during building an associative `array` from the `string`. Each character will be a key and will count the number as value.

```
$sample = "abbcabz";

$check = [];
for($i=0; $i<strlen($sample); $i++)
{
    if(!array_key_exists($sample[$i], $check))
    {
        $check[$sample[$i]] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $check[$sample[$i]] += 1;
    }
}

echo array_search(1, $check);
```