# Algorithm:Find first non-repeated character in an input string

Tags: java, algorithm

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511340/find-the-first-non-repeated-character-in-a-string) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955586/how-to-find-first-non-repetitive-character-from-a-string) question but mine is different. I want to write an efficient code for it in java. I came up with 2 solutions:

### Approach 1.

```
find_first_reapeted(char[] input)
{
    HashMap<Character,Integer> myhash = new HashMap<Character,Integer> ();
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++)
    {
      if(myhash.containsKey(input[i])
          myhash.put(input[i],2); //just put 2 even if it is more than 2
      else
          myhash.put(input[i],1);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++)
    {
      if(myhash.getValue(input[i])==1)
         return input[i];
    }
}
```

### Approach 2.

```
find_first_reapeted(char[] input)
{
    int[] allchars = new int[26];
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++)
    {
        allchars[input[i]-'a'] += 1;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++)
    {
      if(allchars[input[i]-'a']==1)
         return input[i];
    }
}
```

First is there any better solution? (int term of time and space complexity)?
If not which one of the the above is better? I'm not sure about the space complexity of hashmap!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For my 2 cents worth, I might suggest that because you have to loop the entire string from start to finish, neither are particular inefficient for the task you've described....IHMO

Answer (score 3):

How about

The first repeating character.

```
char find_first_repeated(char[] input) {
    BitSet bs = new BitSet();
    for(char c : input) {
        if(bs.get(c))
           return c;
        bs.set(c);
    }
    return '\uffff'; // invalid char
}
```

The first non repeating character, I would use the second approach but using the for-each loop to make it cleaner.

Comment: Why BitSet instead of HashMap ?

Comment: @aauser BitSet uses 1 bit per bit, `HashMap<Character, Integer>` uses about 80 bytes or 640 bits per entry.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Can you tell me how you compute space for hashmap?

Comment: @sweet Sure http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/size-of-entry-in-map.html

Comment: The title of the question asks for the first *non*-repeated character, and the OPs code also seems to imply this.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Good point, In that case I would use the second approach but prettier.